# Responsive thumbnail / fixed thumbs

Tags: css

I'm having trouble making my portfolio thumbnail work in a responsive way. I'm working with media queries, so my thumbs are 33.3% of their containers, 50% or 100% depending on device width (3,2 or 1 colum).

I want the thumbs to be square. How can I make height be equal to width and images fill in those squares?

As it is, divs can't be in a regular grid, as they have different heights.

Here's my code so far.

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/a.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/b.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/b1.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/c.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/c1.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/d.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/b.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
    <div class="th">
        <img src="img/a.jpg" class="pre" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.thumbnail-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.th {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.thumbnail-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.th {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks the answer is adding .resize as follow:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var cw = $('.wrapre').width();
        $('.wrapre').css({'height':cw+'px'});
    });
</script>
```

It seems to work!

Thanks Cody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JQuery such as the example below.

var cw = $('.child').width();
$('.child').css({'height':cw+'px'});

Comment: Thanks! It almost works, but there's something wrong. I added alerts to check width and height, and they are the same so that's ok. But when screen is wide, divs overlap, and when narrow, a white space appears below images... I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that when refresh the page it's ok, and then when resizing, heights changes. How can I make that scripts to work all the time?